# Can a mod resurrect my deleted question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Out of idle curiosity and to see what would happen as a low-rep SU user, I deleted one of my unanswered questions (yes, I know, stupid):

https://superuser.com/questions/278552/improving-windows-7-network-device-discovery-speed

It would appear that I am not permitted to see my own deleted questions and therefore resurrect it (which in itself raises the question as to why?).

Could a mod please undelete this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been revived.

A few relevant Meta.SO posts I've managed to pull up:

[Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

[Allow users to be able to see their own deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32675/allow-users-to-be-able-to-see-their-own-deleted-questions)

Comment: well it's [status-bydesign]. I believe if you know the direct link, you can view it, but doesn't show up under your questions

Comment: @Sathya - Kev has the direct link, it's in the question, but still indicates that he could not access it.

Comment: Ah, I seem to have missed that

Comment: appreciated and thanks for the links.